# Подключение по VPN Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, vpn

До определённого момента с подключением по VPN было все в порядке. Но 10 дней назад возможность подключения исчезла и высвечивается сообщение:

```
"The VPN connection "Name_VPN_Connection" disconected because VPN service stopped"
```

При этом к другому VPN серверу подключение в порядке.
Это подключение пересоздавал, но безтолку.

Настораживает в логах:

```
NetworkManager[2759]: CHAP authentication failed
```

В чём может быть причина?

```
uname -a
Linux laptop 4.4.0-36-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 11 18:01:55 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: «аутентификация неудачна». неправильный логин или пароль. обращайтесь к администраторам/техподдержке сервера.

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопрос следует адресовать в соответствующую техподдержку.